# Bad request 400 with URL containing curly brackets in Golang

Tags: url, go, curly-braces

Coming from Python

```
import requests    
requests.get('https://git.eclipse.org/r/changes/?q=since:{2018-01-01 00:00:00.000}+AND+until:{2018-01-01 22:59:59.999}')
```

works like a charm.

In Go,

```
client := &http.Client{Timeout: time.Second * 10}
response, err := client.Get("https://git.eclipse.org/r/changes/?q=since:{2018-01-01 00:00:00.000}+AND+until:{2018-01-01 22:59:59.999}")
```

causes a bad request (400).

I assume, that the problem is the encoding of the curly brackets in the URL. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the query string:

```
 client.Get("https://git.eclipse.org/r/changes/?q=" + url.QueryEscape("since:{2018-01-01 00:00:00.000}+AND+until:{2018-01-01 22:59:59.999}"))
```

you may need to change the `+` back to spaces since they are being escaped.